# Updating Multiple fields values between records in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Using SQL 2012

I have two tables that exist one to one on M_id(there are no duplicates in either table) but that are not identical records but have some of the same fields defined but just in different columns.

I need to do a value check, and if a "1" appears in a specific cell in tableA, I need to update that field to a "1" in tableB.

EXAMPLE:

TableA

```
M_id | L1 | L2 | L3 
100  | 0  | 1  | 0
```

TableB

```
M_id | S1 | S2 | S3
100  | 0  | 0  | 0
```

The relationship here is L2 = S3, so if a "1" is encountered in L2, I need S3 to be updated to a "1".  All tableB values will be a "0" until updated.

The other columns need updates the same way as L1=S2, and L3=S1 and such.

Not so sure how this might happen.

Thanks,

MP

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you mean correctly.

```
WITH cte (
    SELECT
        a.L2
        , b.S3
    FROM
        tableB b
        JOIN tableA a ON a.M_id = b.M_id
    WHERE
        b.L2 = 1
)
UPDATE cte
SET S3 = L2, S2 = L1, S1 = L3
```

Comment: Hi, well the join needs to be by matching M_id's, an then the check is to see if any L's have a value of "1", they need to update their "matching" field in TableB with the relationships of L1=S2, L2 = S3, and L3=S1.

Comment: I will give this a try!  Thank you!